# Grid Computing vs Distributed Computing

Tags: cloud

I would like to ask what is the difference between grid computing and distributed computing? Do anyone has the overall architecture of them?

Comment: Try read here: https://www.researchgate.net/post/What_is_the_difference_between_grid_computing_systems_and_distributed_systems#:~:text=The%20key%20distinction%20between%20distributed,each%20node%20has%20its%20own

Comment: Thanks for your response. Anyone also confused about them can refer to: http://docshare04.docshare.tips/files/4834/48345816.pdf